# how to stop python from "binding" variables that stand for lists

Tags: python

In python, the code

```
x = 0
y = x
y = 1
print x
```

returns "0" while the code

```
x = [0]
y = x
y[0] = 1
print x
```

returns "[1]".   **Why does python treat lists so differently from integers and what can I do to force it to treat the bottom "x" as it does the top "x"?**    It seems like the '='s in the respective second lines mean different things - the top one only affects y while the bottom somehow binds x to y.  So maybe I need to use a different symbol in the bottom code?

Comment: No, they are doing the exact same thing. Read this: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: There are no strings involved here (except for the conversion done by `print`), what you have is a *list*.  `y = x` on a *mutable* object like a list is just a reference assignment, the object they reference is the same.

Comment: It's because `x` and `y` refer to the same object.

Comment: But the `=`s in "the respective third lines" **are doing smth totally different**.

Comment: @cdarke right, thanks I've edited it.

Comment: @CristiFati ok that makes sense. So how do I make python see x and y as different lists.  Because I want to be able to manipulate y without changing x.

Comment: @Timkinsella Check the answers for [How to clone or copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2612802/2063361)

Comment: `y = x[:]`. But I'm sure this topic is also covered by many [SO](https://stackoverflow.com) questions.

Comment: ok, that should do it. thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = [20, 21]
b = [20, 21]

print(a is b) # False
print(a == b) # True
print(id(a) != id(b)) # True
```

`a` and `b` have the same value, but do not refer to the same object.

```
x = [1]
y = x

print(x is y) # True
print(x == y) # True
print(id(x) == id(y)) # True
```

`x` and `y` have the same value and refer to the same object.

```
i = [0]
j = i[:] # Copy of i

print(i is j) # False
print(i == j) # True
print(id(i) != id(j)) # True
```

`i` and `j` have the same value, but do not refer to the same object.